# Dynamically create FTP accounts for each user

Tags: php, linux, ftp

I'm looking to provide a facility for all users on my site to have their own FTP account to a personal folder that they own on the same server.

From what i think, I will need to execute shell commands from php to create an ftp account everytime a new user is created. I understand this might be FTP server dependent and the commands vary, but are there any suggestions on which FTP server would be best for this use ? Any APIs scripts available to interface with ftp servers ?

Also, alternate solutions are welcome

Comment: You really should ask a specific programming question about a specific setup. Your question as-is, is a bit open ended and too far from programming question for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use proftpd with a MySQL. Here's a [howto](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/SQL.html).

The only PHP you need to write is to insert the user account into the MySQL table.